# How to solve the NOT NULL constraint failed Error in Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting an IntegrityError when I want to save a new **course** on my e-learning website. Of course, I have searched for a similar solution on StackOverflow but I couldn't find an appropriate way for my solution.

here are my models

**UserAccount Model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class UserAccount(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255, verbose_name='email', unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,  unique=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Course Model**

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import UserAccount
class Course(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        UserAccount, related_name='courses_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover/", null=True, blank=True)
```

Also, my course form is here

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['curriculum', 'title', 'description', 'cover_photo']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3})
        }
```

So in my view, I like to send the list of my courses to the template and also my **CourseForm()** using the *get_context_data* method. The code is bellow

My class-based view

```
class OwnerListMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerListMixin, LoginRequiredMixin,  PermissionRequiredMixin):
    model = Course
    fields = ['curriculum', 'title', 'description', 'cover_photo']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')

class ManageCourseListView(OwnerCourseMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "courses_app/manage/course/list.html"
    permission_required = "courses_app.view_course"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CourseForm()
        return context
```

but when I render the form in my template to save a new course I get the following Error

> IntegrityError at /create/
> NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_app_course.owner_id

CREATE VIEW

```
class CourseCreateView(OwnerCourseMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = "courses_app.add_course"
    template_name = "courses_app/manage/course/form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("manage_course_list")
```

Comment: Can you please post the code where you save your form.

Comment: You mean my form? if so this is my form.html `<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{  form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>`

Comment: The error occurs after submitting the form, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly after I submit the form the error occurs

Comment: Can you please post the CreateView. You have only posted the ListView. What the error tells you is that you need to set a user as owner. This info needs to be passed to the form before saving

Comment: yes, but I already sent the id of the owner by using the get_queryset()

Comment: No, this method only selects the courses to display. It does not set fields in your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the user as the owner what currently is not happening. The form is being saved with the fields you have set. There are multiple ways of adding the user. You could do it this way.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class CourseCreateView(OwnerCourseMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = "courses_app.add_course"
    template_name = "courses_app/manage/course/form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("manage_course_list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.owner = self.request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: I also want to create my form inside a modal in my list_course.html. How can I do that? for now, it redirects me to form.html and I don't want that