# how can i store data created in a website dynamically to database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was thinking about creating a todo website were each user can create their own to-do list and when they click on save, the data should be stored in the database were they can access the history when they re-login. The Listview will contain several date where they can see past to-do data. I am not getting how i can store this data associated with each user

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to add the user as part of the model and then set the user before saving. Here is an example how to do it: [How to solve the NOT NULL constraint failed Error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353184/how-to-solve-the-not-null-constraint-failed-error-in-django/67353580?noredirect=1#comment119050684_67353580)